# How to access header information on node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io

How can i read **cookie**  on **node js** ??

```
var socket  = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 8000;
var mysql = require('mysql');


function parseCookies (request) {
    var list = {},
        rc = request.headers.cookie;

    rc && rc.split(';').forEach(function( cookie ) {
        var parts = cookie.split('=');
        list[parts.shift().trim()] = decodeURI(parts.join('='));
    });

    return list;
}


 http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  // To Read a Cookie
    var user_id= cookies.realtimeid;
    console.log(user_id);
});




server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
  var cookies = parseCookies();
  console.log(cookies);

});
```

I am new on node and socket. I have to read cookie value that is set by **codeignter.**
How can i send header request on **parseCookies** from **server.listen**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you are using express, so I suggest you to use the very well known module for it. cookie-parser https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser

**Installation**

```
npm install cookie-parser
```

**HOW TO USE IT**

```
var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())
```

So basically after your mysql require you can do `app.use(cookieParser())`

And then in every request you do in the `req` variable you will find the cookies with `req.cookies`
**Example**

```
var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Cookies: ", req.cookies)
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: sir is there any other way.
i have edited my code ..
all i need to do  is make **http.createServer** to listen my port and set that user_id global

Comment: Why do you want to make things so complicated, while what you need is to add 2 lines and remove most of the ones you have written?

Comment: Ok I will look into it. Thank you for Your Response

Comment: Thank You it works ...  
`app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var cookies=req.cookies;
  var user_id=cookies.realtimeid;
  console.log(user_id);

});`
now can i make this user_id global